# (Permantly) Change a Window Class Type

Tags: autohotkey

I'm looking for a way to change a program window class into another. Change the window's title is easy, while I didn't find anything for classes. Can you help me?

Comment: You can't change a class.

Comment: What's the point in changing the class name? Please specify your intentions.

Comment: I have a software that display a window over another specific window. Given the title name and the window class, that software indentify on which window should be placed the other window. My goal is to trick that software to display its window into my custom one. Alternatively I can compile a custom AHK build, ah wait, I tried but I got too many errors even if I followed the tutorial. I guess this is way beyond my poor skills

Comment: So you create your own GUI using AHK? In this case, there's at least a hackish solution for compiled scripts: [click](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/3388-compiled-scripts-window-class/?p=52356).

Comment: Edit the .bin file doesn't work, at least for me. When I compile it everything works fine, but an error prevents me to start the script